# Titan graph database too slow with 100000+ vertices with indices how to optimize it?

Tags: database, optimization, graph, titan

Here is the indices code:

```
`
g = TitanFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cassandra")
            .set("storage.hostname", "127.0.0.1").open();

    TitanManagement mgmt = g.getManagementSystem();

    PropertyKey db_local_name = mgmt.makePropertyKey("db_local_name")
            .dataType(String.class).make();
    mgmt.buildIndex("byDb_local_name", Vertex.class).addKey(db_local_name)
            .buildCompositeIndex();

    PropertyKey db_schema = mgmt.makePropertyKey("db_schema")
            .dataType(String.class).make();
    mgmt.buildIndex("byDb_schema", Vertex.class).addKey(db_schema)
            .buildCompositeIndex();

    PropertyKey db_column = mgmt.makePropertyKey("db_column")
            .dataType(String.class).make();
    mgmt.buildIndex("byDb_column", Vertex.class).addKey(db_column)
            .buildCompositeIndex();

    PropertyKey type = mgmt.makePropertyKey("type").dataType(String.class)
            .make();
    mgmt.buildIndex("byType", Vertex.class).addKey(type)
            .buildCompositeIndex();

    PropertyKey value = mgmt.makePropertyKey("value")
            .dataType(Object.class).make();
    mgmt.buildIndex("byValue", Vertex.class).addKey(value)
            .buildCompositeIndex();

    PropertyKey index = mgmt.makePropertyKey("index")
            .dataType(Integer.class).make();
    mgmt.buildIndex("byIndex", Vertex.class).addKey(index)
            .buildCompositeIndex();

    mgmt.commit();`
```

Here is the search for vertices and then add vertex with 3 edges on 3GHz 2GB RAM pc. It does 830 vertices in 3 hours and I have 100,000 data its too slow. The code is below:

```
for (Object[] rowObj : list) {
            // TXN_ID
            Iterator<Vertex> iter = g.query()
                    .has("db_local_name", "Report Name 1")
                    .has("db_schema", "MPS").has("db_column", "txn_id")
                    .has("value", rowObj[0]).vertices().iterator();
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                vertex1 = iter.next();
                logger.debug("vertex1=" + vertex1.getId() + ","
                        + vertex1.getProperty("db_local_name") + ","
                        + vertex1.getProperty("db_schema") + ","
                        + vertex1.getProperty("db_column") + ","
                        + vertex1.getProperty("type") + ","
                        + vertex1.getProperty("index") + ","
                        + vertex1.getProperty("value"));
            }
            // TXN_TYPE
            iter = g.query().has("db_local_name", "Report Name 1")
                    .has("db_schema", "MPS").has("db_column", "txn_type")
                    .has("value", rowObj[1]).vertices().iterator();
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                vertex2 = iter.next();
                logger.debug("vertex2=" + vertex2.getId() + ","
                        + vertex2.getProperty("db_local_name") + ","
                        + vertex2.getProperty("db_schema") + ","
                        + vertex2.getProperty("db_column") + ","
                        + vertex2.getProperty("type") + ","
                        + vertex2.getProperty("index") + ","
                        + vertex2.getProperty("value"));
            }
            // WALLET_ID
            iter = g.query().has("db_local_name", "Report Name 1")
                    .has("db_schema", "MPS").has("db_column", "wallet_id")
                    .has("value", rowObj[2]).vertices().iterator();
            if (iter.hasNext()) {
                vertex3 = iter.next();
                logger.debug("vertex3=" + vertex3.getId() + ","
                        + vertex3.getProperty("db_local_name") + ","
                        + vertex3.getProperty("db_schema") + ","
                        + vertex3.getProperty("db_column") + ","
                        + vertex3.getProperty("type") + ","
                        + vertex3.getProperty("index") + ","
                        + vertex3.getProperty("value"));
            }

            vertex4 = g.addVertex(null);
            vertex4.setProperty("db_local_name", "Report Name 1");
            vertex4.setProperty("db_schema", "MPS");
            vertex4.setProperty("db_column", "amount");
            vertex4.setProperty("type", "indivisual_0");
            vertex4.setProperty("value", rowObj[3].toString());
            vertex4.setProperty("index", i);

            vertex1.addEdge("data", vertex4);
            logger.debug("vertex1 added");
            vertex2.addEdge("data", vertex4);
            logger.debug("vertex2 added");
            vertex3.addEdge("data", vertex4);
            logger.debug("vertex3 added");
            i++;
            g.commit();
        }
```

Is there anyway to optimize this code?

Comment: I had performance problems too. I upgraded to 8GB of ram, and I saw a greater than 400% performance boost compared to 4GB. I was running close to 100% ram usage, which I guess meant that it was using the swap-disk and thus reading from HDD on ram-caches etc. Not good. Run some tests and see what your bottleneck is, but my guess is that it is ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, this question was answered in the Aurelius Graphs mailing list:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/XKT6aokRfFI

Basically:

1. build/use a real composite index:
   `mgmt.buildIndex("by_local_name_schema_value", Vertex.class).addKey(db_local_name).addKey(db_schema).addKey(value).buildComposite();`
2. don't call `g.commit()` after each loop cycle, instead do something
   like this: `if (++1%10000 == 0) g.commit()`
3. turn on `storage.batch-loading` if not already doing so
4. if all you can throw at cassandra is 2G of RAM consider using BerkleyDB.  Cassandra [prefers 4G](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraHardware) of RAM minimum and would probably like "more"
5. I don't know the nature of your data, but can you pre-sort it and use `BatchGraph` as described in the [Powers of Ten - Part I](http://thinkaurelius.com/2014/05/29/powers-of-ten-part-i/) blog post and in the [wiki](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Batch-Implementation#presorting-data) - Using `BatchGraph` would prevent you from having to maintain the transaction described in number 2 above.

Comment: Its still so slow I cannot take it to production.

Comment: i've added some more options for you to my answer.  830 vertices and 3 times as many edges doesn't really make sense to me.